# Why isn't my group_by function working in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by

I'm using R 4.3.0 with the latest dplyr version 1.1.2 and unable to get group_by working

I have a function that is ignoring my group_by command.  I've tried a number of approaches, including passing the parameter quoted and unquoted.  I either get 3 identical rows, each summarizing correctly the full data.frame or just one row correctly summarizing the full data frame.  I have 3 levels in my by variable, 1,2,3,which is named cohort.  I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks, Gerard.

```
    dplyr::group_by(.data[[grouping]]) %>%
    
    dplyr::summarize(
        n       = sum     (!is.na(var)),
        nmiss   = sum     (is.na(var)),
        mean    = mean    (var, na.rm=T),
        sd      = sd      (var, na.rm=T),
        se      = sd/sqrt(n),
        lower   = mean -  as.numeric(qt(0.975, df=n-1)*se),
        upper   = mean +  as.numeric(qt(0.975, df=n-1)*se),
        min     = min     (var, na.rm=T),
        max     = max     (var, na.rm=T),
        median  = median  (var, na.rm=T),                    
        q1      = quantile(var, 0.25, na.rm=T),
        q3      = quantile(var, 0.75, na.rm=T),
        iqr     = IQR     (var, na.rm=T)) %>%
      
    dplyr::mutate(
        n     = round(n,            digits=0),
        nmiss = round(nmiss,        digits=0),
        mean  = format(round(mean,  digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        median= format(round(median,digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        sd    = format(round(sd,    digits=n_digit+1), nsmall=n_digit+1),
        se    = format(round(se,    digits=n_digit+1), nsmall=n_digit+1),
        min   = format(round(min,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        max   = format(round(max,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        q1    = format(round(q1,    digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        q3    = format(round(q3,    digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        iqr   = format(round(iqr,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        lower = format(round(lower, digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        upper = format(round(upper, digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit)) %>%
      
    dplyr::mutate(
        range=paste0(min,  ', ', max),
        x_sd =paste0(mean, ' (', sd,')'),
        ci   =paste0(lower,', ', upper),
        q1q3 =paste0(q1,   ', ', q3))
}

ds01=run_stats(inds=mr, grouping="cohort", var=mrse, n_digit=3)

ds01
```

expecting a 3 lines of output, each summarizing the 3 levels of my grouping variable.

I tried sending quoted and unquoted values.  I tried putting the variable in {{}}, in [[]], and !!varname, with no luck.

test data used by funcition:

```
#buld test tibble

mr  <-tribble (
  ~id, ~cohort, ~mrse,
  1, 1, -0.6,
  2, 1, -0.2,
  3, 1, -0.3,
  4, 1, -0.3,
  5, 1, -0.2,
  6, 1, -1.0,
  7, 1, -2.0,
  8, 1, -1.5,
  9, 1, -0.2,
 10, 1, -0.1,
 11, 2,  0.6,
 12, 2,  2.2,
 13, 2,  0.3,
 14, 2,  3.3,
 15, 2,  1.2,
 16, 2,  1.0,
 17, 2,  4.0,
 18, 2,  1.5,
 19, 2,  0.2,
 20, 2,  0.1,
 21, 3, -0.6,
 22, 3,  0.2,
 23, 3, -0.3,
 24, 3,  0.3,
 25, 3, -0.2,
 26, 3,  1.0,
 27, 3,  0.0,
 28, 3, -0.5,
 29, 3,  0.2,
 30, 3, -0.1)
```

Comment: I think you're missing the `function(...)` declaration itself, is it safe to assume that the first line of the code block should be `run_stats <- function(.data, grouping, var, n_digit) {`?

Comment: I wonder if this is due to the complication of [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), and naming variables the same as R functions. You use of `var=mrse` suggests that you think it should be using non-standard evaluation with your function, but you are instead trying to use it directly, which shouldn't work. You're already passing `grouping="cohort"` and using it with `.data[[grouping]]`, why not pass `var="mrse"` and referencing it internally as `.data[[var]]`?

Comment: data %>% dplyr::group_by(grouping)    ....

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into the `{{...}}` syntax from ?`rlang`? (admittedly I'm not sure where the syntax is from). Nonetheless, this just takes a little non-standard eval for the variable names and no quotes.

```r
library(tidyverse)

run_stats <- function(inds, grouping, var, n_digit){

  dplyr::group_by(inds, {{grouping}}) %>%
    
    dplyr::summarize(
        n       = sum     (!is.na({{var}})),
        nmiss   = sum     (is.na({{var}})),
        mean    = mean    ({{var}}, na.rm=T),
        sd      = sd      ({{var}}, na.rm=T),
        se      = sd/sqrt(n),
        lower   = mean -  as.numeric(qt(0.975, df=n-1)*se),
        upper   = mean +  as.numeric(qt(0.975, df=n-1)*se),
        min     = min     ({{var}}, na.rm=T),
        max     = max     ({{var}}, na.rm=T),
        median  = median  ({{var}}, na.rm=T),                    
        q1      = quantile({{var}}, 0.25, na.rm=T),
        q3      = quantile({{var}}, 0.75, na.rm=T),
        iqr     = IQR     ({{var}}, na.rm=T)) %>%
      
    dplyr::mutate(
        n     = round(n,            digits=0),
        nmiss = round(nmiss,        digits=0),
        mean  = format(round(mean,  digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        median= format(round(median,digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        sd    = format(round(sd,    digits=n_digit+1), nsmall=n_digit+1),
        se    = format(round(se,    digits=n_digit+1), nsmall=n_digit+1),
        min   = format(round(min,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        max   = format(round(max,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        q1    = format(round(q1,    digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        q3    = format(round(q3,    digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        iqr   = format(round(iqr,   digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        lower = format(round(lower, digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit),
        upper = format(round(upper, digits=n_digit),   nsmall=n_digit)) %>%
      
    dplyr::mutate(
        range=paste0(min,  ', ', max),
        x_sd =paste0(mean, ' (', sd,')'),
        ci   =paste0(lower,', ', upper),
        q1q3 =paste0(q1,   ', ', q3))
}

ds01=run_stats(inds=mr, grouping=cohort, var=mrse, n_digit=3)

ds01
#> # A tibble: 3 x 18
#>   cohort     n nmiss mean     sd     se     lower upper min   max   median q1   
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#> 1      1    10     0 "-0.640" 0.6518 0.2061 "-1.~ "-0.~ "-2.~ "-0.~ "-0.3~ "-0.~
#> 2      2    10     0 " 1.440" 1.3410 0.4241 " 0.~ " 2.~ " 0.~ " 4.~ " 1.1~ " 0.~
#> 3      3    10     0 " 0.000" 0.4619 0.1461 "-0.~ " 0.~ "-0.~ " 1.~ "-0.0~ "-0.~
#> # ... with 6 more variables: q3 <chr>, iqr <chr>, range <chr>, x_sd <chr>,
#> #   ci <chr>, q1q3 <chr>
```

Comment: That did the trick!  I had to put var and grouping in {{}} to get it to work, as you suggested.  I was not understanding that  I was passing objects, which did not require {{}} and variables (with different values) that did require the {{}}  Thanks very much for your correction.  Gerard